# How manage dependencies between jar files?

Tags: java, jar, compilation

I have to compile a list of file .java for create 2 file jar
and use this files as client and library.

Runining theme in this way

```
java -cp lib.jar:client.jar MainClass
```

although i succeded in creating lib.jar, compiling the file for client requires a file that is in lib.jar.
The question is, how can i create a jar file that requires one or more other jar files?

Comment: given that lib.jar compiled, you should be able to run "javac -cp lib.jar client.java" changing your paths as appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

Generally you can use build tools like maven/ant with dependency manager like (maven & ivy, gradle, grape) to do this for you

Comment: +1 for Maven
AFAIK, Maven doesn't use Ivy (Maven has a built-in dependency management). But you can use Ivy with Ant.

Comment: I mentioned it because you wrote "Maven & Ivy" ;-)

Comment: yeah could be well phrased, anyways it should be clear enough now